# Why is String.prototype.indexOf() more performant than a for loop?

Tags: javascript, performance

I was under the impression that `indexOf` was essentially a `for` loop behind the scenes. But, consider the following:

```js
const str = 'abcdefjhijklmnopqrstuvwxy'.repeat(10000) + 'z';
let before, after;

before = Date.now();
str.indexOf('z');
after = Date.now();

console.log('Time for indexOf', after - before);

before = Date.now();
for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (str[i] === 'z') {
    break;
  }
}
after = Date.now();

console.log('Time for for loop', after - before);
```

Why is `indexOf` faster when the string is sufficiently long?

Comment: I get `Time for indexOf 14`, `Time for for loop 274` (on my first run). Your test is not a good one. One single test of a function isn't enough to draw any useful conclusions. You need to repeat a test many times. My later runs give me `0` and `4` most of the time.

Comment: you should at least specify what js engine you are talking about.

Comment: As to why, it's probably because most JS engines have some native code optimizations around common functions like `IndexOf`.

Comment: Any sensible browser implementation of JavaScript is going to be native code for the spec-defined parts of the API. `indexOf` is going to run at native performance, whereas your for loop is going to run at whatever performance the JS interpreter yields. Try `console.log(String.prototype.indexOf.toString())` and you'll probably see it reported as `function indexOf() { [native code] }`.

Comment: If you hassle the JIT thing enough it will do more work to try and produce faster code - there is a balance between the time taken to (optimise code and do it) and the time taken to (just do it the obvious way right now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some further optimizations you can do with the `for` loop: first, don't re-calculate the string's length on every iteration. Secondly, don't reassign (`=`) - you want to *compare* (with `===`). Thirdly, use `performance.now()` instead of `Date.now()` when looking at very small time scales:

```js
const str = 'abcdefjhijklmnopqrstuvwxy'.repeat(1000000) + 'z';
let before, after;

before = performance.now();
str.indexOf('z');
after = performance.now();

console.log('Time for indexOf', after - before);

const strArray = [...str];
const strLength = strArray.length;
before = performance.now();
for (let i = 0; i < strLength; i++) {
  if (strArray[i] === 'z') {
    break;
  }
}
after = performance.now();

console.log('Time for for loop', after - before);
```

But the `for` loop still has unnecessary baggage - `indexOf` on a string can operate at a lower level than the code in a `for` loop - iterating over characters in a string is exactly what it's designed for - so the `indexOf` runs faster.